# How to convert a string to a series of integers?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

Making an RPG and want the currency to be represented in platinum, gold, silver and copper.  Unfortunately, my professor wants the currency stored as a string (i.e. string class, not cStrings).  For example -- 0.1.23.15 would be 0 platinum, 1 gold, 23 silver and 15 copper.

I would just like to know the big idea of how to implement this.  For example -- could I use strtok (i.e. I believe this only works on cStrings) or some other C++ function to accomplish this?

Comment: Use `find`, `substr` and there's your strtok?

Comment: There's a nice question on here about splitting strings. There's also a `std::split` proposal in the works, but I don't think your professor can wait that long :p

Comment: sscanf on the c_str() of your string? match the pattern "%d.%d.%d.%d"

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string str="0.1.23.15",temp;
    stringstream s(str);
    vector<int> v;

    while(getline(s,temp,'.'))
    {
        v.push_back(stoi(temp));
    }

    for(int i: v) cout << i << endl;//C++11 style
    //for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) cout << v[i] << endl; //Old school :D
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is good but you don't need system("pause") when you can use `std::cin.get()`, no `using namespace std` and the range based for loop is technically not the same same the regular for loop under it.